# How to get data in chunks from an API using rxjs interval and stop when there is no data left

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I am trying to load data in chunks on timely basis. for this I am using thee methods.

**This function loads data from a json object that I am using to mimic api data**

```
 getScrollingData(startIndex, endIndex){
    if(this.items.data.length>endIndex){
      return of(this.items.data.slice(startIndex, endIndex));
    }else{
      return of(null)
    }
  }
```

**The getData method below is being used to send request every two seconds**

```
getData(){
const secondsCounter = interval(2000); 
return secondsCounter
.pipe(
  flatMap((res) => {
    if(res!=null)
     return this.mimicApiService.getScrollingData(res, res+10)
            .takeUntil(v => v != null)// this causes error
  }),
  
  
)
```

}

**In the ngOnInit of component I am subscribing to  getData to load that data into array to be displayed on the screen**

```
data = [];
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataService.getData().subscribe((res)=>{
    this.data = [...this.data, ...res];
  });
}
```

**Questions**

1. I am getting error `Argument of type '(v: any) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<any>'` from takeUntil. Can you please tell why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong operator, takeUntil wants an observable and will stop taking once that observable emits.

What you need is takeWhile, which suits your use case better:

```
takeWhile(v => v != null)
```

and here is the [doc](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/takeWhile)

Edit:
if you also want to stop the interval when there is no more data returned from `getScrollingData`, you can do something like the following:

```
getData() {
  const stopInterval = new Subject();
  const secondsCounter = interval(2000)
    .pipe(takeUntil(stopInterval));
  return secondsCounter
    .pipe(
      flatMap((res) => {
        if (res != null)
          return this.getScrollingData(res, res + 2)
      }),
      takeWhile(v => {
        if (v == null) {
          stopInterval.next();
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }))
}
```

once we emit from stopInterval, `takeUntil` of interval will trigger.

Comment: This stops inner Observable from running but, outer Observable  (interval) still giving counting